# Convert Class component into a handleChange Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-functional-component

I'm wanting to convert this class component into a `handleChange` event that works in a function component. I'm not entirely sure that's possible, it may have to be a hook. I can't quite get the syntax right.

```
class CheckboxForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: [] };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const input = event.target.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        value: this.state.value.includes(input)
          ? this.state.value.filter((item) => item !== input)
          : [...this.state.value, input],
      },
      () => {
        console.log("CheckBox: ", this.state.value);
      }
    );
  }
```

My attempt:

```
export const CheckboxHook = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const handleCheckbox = (event) => {
    const input = event.target.value;
    setValue(
      value.include(input)
        ? value.filter((item) => item !== input)
        : [value, input],
      () => {
        console.log("Checkbox: ", value);
      }
    );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to do something like this? You don't need any custom hooks for it - just `useState` and `useEffect`.

```
const CheckboxForm = (props) => {
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // equivalent to passing a callback to `this.setState` in class component
    console.log("Checked: ", checkedItems);
  }, [checkedItems])

  const handleCheckbox = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    // setting with hooks must use a callback
    // if you need access to the previous value
    setCheckedItems(items =>
      items.includes(value)
        ? items.filter(item => item !== value)
        : [...items, value]
    );
  };

  return <form>
    <label>a <input value="a" type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckbox} /></label>
    <label>b <input value="b" type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckbox} /></label>
    <label>c <input value="c" type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckbox} /></label>
  </form>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom hook to wrap your handler logic and use it like:

```js
const useHandleChange = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const input = event.target.value;
    setValue(
      {
        value: value.includes(input)
          ? value.filter((item) => item !== input)
          : [...value, input],
      },
      () => {
        console.log("CheckBox: ", value);
      }
    );
  };

  return { value, handleChange };
};

// Usage
const { value, handleChange } = useHandleChange();

// In the render
<Input onChange={handleChange} value={value} />
```